# Are there unwanted consequences to non-PEP8 compliant code (E211)?

Tags: python, pep8

Let's say there is a function defined with:

```
def thingy(arg1):
    pass
```

I know that the right way to call it, according to books and PEP8 ([error code E211](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes)), is:

```
thingy(true)
```

However, I have also seen this following form in existing code:

```
thingy (true)
```

Apart from being against PEP8, can it be harmful?

In particular, can it create an unwanted bug/side-effect that would not be thrown using the recommended way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, whitespace is not significant, when used between a callable object an the call parentheses.

From the [lexical analysis reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#whitespace-between-tokens):

> Except at the beginning of a logical line or in string literals, the **whitespace characters space, tab and formfeed can be used interchangeably to separate tokens**. Whitespace is needed between two tokens only if their concatenation could otherwise be interpreted as a different token (e.g., ab is one token, but a b is two tokens).

and

> Besides NEWLINE, INDENT and DEDENT, the following categories of tokens exist: identifiers, keywords, literals, operators, and delimiters. **Whitespace characters (other than line terminators, discussed earlier) are not tokens**, but serve to delimit tokens. Where ambiguity exists, a token comprises the longest possible string that forms a legal token, when read from left to right.

Emphasis mine.

Where whitespace is not needed, it has no meaning other than to separate the tokens visually. `thingy` and `(` are already two separate tokens, and won't be confused as *one* token when whitespace is absent. So the presence of whitespace here doesn't change the interpretation of the line.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the detailed answer! I prefer the `thingy(true)` form though as it respects PEP8, and I don't see why one would use the other form apart from personal preference.

Comment: @JérémieAstori: unless the project you work on is already using a different convention, sticking to PEP8 is a great idea.